# MySQL: Missing Queries - how to diagnose?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm using MySQL 5 with InnoDB and I'm dealing with some larger tables (10-100 million records).

Some of those tables get millions of updates per day.

I noticed that updates might just be 'missing' when I have a very database-heavy day.
E.g. 30% of all updates never get written on such days, which is terrible of course.

I cannot see any errors, so my question is how can I diagnose this problem?

Comment: Does your statements use TRANSACTION,COMMIT When error ROALBACK ?

Comment: No they don't. Thanks for your input.